# Rails: Creating instance and associations after checking for existing record (and using the existing record)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a very specific problem, and I cannot seem to find a solution for it. Forgive me if this is too specific, but I don't know where else to ask.

I'm trying to create an instance of a model that has has_many through associations, but the has_many associations are part of a "master" record type table, where only 1 record of something exists (joined together with a join table).

I am trying to implement the following:

Create a Recipe using accepts_nested_attributes_for with Ingredients. The ingredient is to be used only if it is not found in the Ingredients table. If it is found, however, I want to use the already existing record.

If we need a specific example, here goes:

Say we are creating a recipe "Chili" that consists of beans, onions, ground beef. Beans and onions are brand new ingredients (not found in ingredients table) but ground beef already exists in the table. Instead of creating another ground beef record, I want to use the already existing ground beef record found in the ingredients table.

How do I go about doing this?

I thought perhaps I could use a `before save: :check_if_exists` call on the Recipe model, with `check_if_exists` checking through all the form's ingredients if they exist or not. Relevant code:

**Recipe Model**

```
before_save :check_if_exists

def check_if_exists
  self.ingredients.each do |ingredient|
    if Ingredient.exists?(ingredient.name)
      return ingredient
    else
      @ingredient = Ingredient.new(name: ingredient.name)
      return @ingredient
    end
  end
end
```

I know the code above is complete nonsense, but hopefully my idea comes through. I would like to use an existing record if it already exists, otherwise create a new one.

I cannot wrap my head around how to accomplish this, though. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation (https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) says pretty clearly, that you could add `id`s to your hashes of associated records and instead of creating new ingredients old ones will be used.

So I think in your sanitizing method which filters params for saving you could add some verifying if ingredient exists. Something like that:

```
params.require(:recipe).permit(:name, ingredients_attributes: [:name]).tap do |p|
  p[:ingredients_attributes].each do |i|
    ingredient = Ingredient.find_by(name: i[:name])
    i[:id] = ingredient.id if ingredient
  end
end
```